# Why gps-logo doesn't show in status bar?

Tags: cordova, gps, location

I use cordova-2.0.0 and want define coordinaties of user location.
Besides, I want get only gps-coordinates, not a network.
How I can do it? 
Why gps-logo doesn't show in status bar?

My code index.html script :

```
function onSuccess(position) {
        var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'Latitude: '+ position.coords.latitude + '<br />' +
                         'Longitude: '+ position.coords.longitude + '<br />';
    }

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
    //
function onError(error) {
    var element = document.getElementById('geolocation');
    element.innerHTML = 'code: '    + error.code    + '\n' +
              'message: ' + error.message + '\n';
}

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is ready
    function onDeviceReady() {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your updated requirement , you will have to create a native plugin that will check for the  GPS status and depending on the status you can put up an alert in your html page.

Visit [here](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/extending-phonegap-with-native-plugins-for-android.html) for a tutorial on creating native plugin on android.

Answer (score 1):

Oh, It was easily. 
Option - enableHighAccuracy: true. And its working :)

```
function onDeviceReady() {
                // Update every 3 seconds
                var options = { frequency: 3000, enableHighAccuracy: true };
                watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError, options);
            }
```

But how I can define provider using cordova api? 
For example: if gps is off, then application does alert("Please, switch gps on!");

Answer (score 0):

If you can't see the GPS logo in the Status-bar, it's because GPS doesn't start. Maybe one JS-file is not loaded ?

Cordova/phonegap is not native code, there are only three options you could put on watchPosition() function : maximumAge, timeout and enableHighAccuracy (to use GPS). You can just set enableHighAccuracy at true to use GPSProvider and not NetworkBaseProvider.
Maybe you can analyse the error message in onError function to look at if a special message is sent when GPS is disabled.

**Edit :** In my test, no special message appaers, just a timeout message : "Position retrieval timed out." So I think you can't check if GPS is on or off in cordova...

In my opinion, Cordova/phonegap (and all the "crossplatforms" technologies) is not a good choice to develop an app using GPS and others managers like TelephonyManager.

**Nothing can replace native code for that.**

I have an other problem : GPS dont stop when I use clearWatch(): 
Here, my code :

```
var currentTracking = false;
var idwatch = null;

function switchTracking() {
    //when button is pressed to start GPS
    if (!currentTracking) {
        currentTracking = true;
        document.getElementById('switchTracking').value = "Stop GPS"
        tracking();
    }

    //when button is pressed to stop GPS
    else {
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(idwatch);
        currentTracking = false;
        document.getElementById('switchTracking').value = "Start GPS"
    }
}

function tracking() {
    if (currentTracking) {
        idwatch = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(onSuccess, onError,{  timeout: 5000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
    }
    else{
        navigator.geolocation.clearWatch(idwatch);
    }
}

function onSuccess(position) {
   // alert("Gps");

    var lat = document.getElementById('lat');
    var long = document.getElementById('long');
    lat.innerHTML = position.coords.latitude;
    long.innerHTML = position.coords.longitude;
}

// onError Callback receives a PositionError object
//
function onError(error) {
    alert('code: ' + error.code + '\n' +
            'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
}
```